# Highcharter pie chart different size

Tags: r, highcharts, htmlwidgets

I'm plotting two pie charts with the highcharter library and I constantly get the same problem, which is one of the pie charts significantly differs in size from the other.

[image]
This is my code:

```
hchart(activity, "pie", hcaes(x = col, label=col,y = freq, color=colors)) %>%
hc_plotOptions(pie =list(dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE,format="{point.label}:{point.percentage:.2f} %"))) %>%


hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "
Nominal value: {point.y:,.0f}<br>")
```

Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: I just edited the post. It gets plotted the same, way with or without a plot title.

Comment: Issue is with position of labels. The text is taking up most of the horizontal space on chart on the right. You can mess around with position and formatting of the label as well as the length from the pie slice to the text of the ribbon.

Comment: @wergeld is right. I would advice you to use a legend for color indication and plot the values as labels.  That will save the space and you will not use your names and avoid overlap.

Comment: In addition to the above comments - you could also set [size for a pie series](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cpie%3E.size), but dataLabels might not fit, so consider legend instead of dataLabels.